# Increasing the size of Sql Server CE database for a desktop application

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a desktop application that uses the Microsoft Sync Framework to sync a remote SQL Server and a local SQL Server CE database.

4 GB should be enough for the local database size. To allow the local CE database to increase in size I have modified the 'max database size' property in the advanced section to 4091. From what I understand this is included in the connection string.

However, if I open the compact edition database file with SQL Server 2008 and inspect it using right click properties, it tells me that the available space is 864 MB, with 2 MB used. This is worrying as a database with a size of less than 2 GB will most likely not suffice.

Is this a dynamic process whereby it will only increase when needed or is there another step I am missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a runtime property, and designates the size of the memory buffer to be used by the database engine. YOu can simple put "max database size=4091" in your connection string, and the buffer will be able to accomodate a 4 GB database file. Not sure what it is you see in SQL Server Management Studio, sounds wrong and misleading to me. You can read more here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2007/06/13/the-story-of-max-database-size-connection-string-parameter.aspx